# database importing problem with sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions, import

I have a database working in my local sql server 2005 express edition.

I have to import my local database to a remote server database.

For that i established connection to that remote server, and i can now see that database . but when i tried to restore database from my local machine i'm getting an error message when i tried to give backup file location. Below is the error message

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_availablemedia', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

what is the problem, how can i solve this.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, the user connected to the database does not have the required rights to do a database restore. If possible,  grant backup rights by making the user a member of the db_backupoperator role.

```
sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator', 'user02'
```

Answer (score 0):

The user account you use to connect to the database doesn't have the EXECUTE permission. This is needed to perform the restore.